# mysql int vs boolean index

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a task:

records in database can be in statuses:

```
NEW = 1
CONFIRMED = 2
FINISHED = 3
DELETED = 4
```

1.

I can store them in int field, with index for it, and then select like this:

```
... WHERE status = FINISHED ...
... WHERE status = DELETED ...
```

2.

also i can store them as 4 separated boolean fields

and then select:

```
... WHERE finished_field = True ...
... WHERE deleted_field = True ...
```

which case is better in performance (for select) 1 or 2, and does it nessesary create index for fields in case 2?

Comment: It's very likely this will not matter - unless you have billions of records, the performance difference is probably not worth thinking about. I'd say just use a [SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html) and be done with it

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, I'm not sure what difference they would make, but in terms of maintainability, you are better off having a single status field which can take different values rather than having a column for each status. If tomorrow you need a new status, with the second option you would have to change the table schema, whereas with the first option  you just need to use a new status identifier (for example "RESTORED = 5").

Answer (score 0):

Performance will probably not matter. What matters more is the database design. If you use 4 bit fields it is possible to set more than 1 status to `true`. That should not happen. You may prevent that with a trigger but it is better to have one status field since there is only one status.

That way you don't have to combine multiple fields.

Answer (score 0):

The first option will have a better chance to have better performance since you can index that field. Indexing a boolean field has no effect since there are not enough different values and MySQL will ignore that index.

Using one field has a better chance that the index will actually be used.

Finally there are some practical considerations. The first option will make it easier to add another type of status, it will make sure one record can only have one status and your table will be smaller in size.